# How to Use multiple IDs in this script if (!$('#wrapper:visible').length)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redirect

Anyone know how to add multiple ids in this script. i work now only for #wrapper but i want to add some more ids in same script.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    //<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            if (!$('#wrapper:visible').length) window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com/'
        }, 1000)
    })
  //]]>
</script>
```

in the above script it only hold **#wrapper**, and i want to add also **#doom** and **#deem** in that script. what is the syntax ?

Comment: do you want this to be an && or || operator?  If all them are visible or just want one of them to be visible?

Comment: @Clayton if any of these visible, i think for this it uses or operator, please share full code with me, so i check here, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add more ID's in the selector, and just filter on `:visible`

```
if ( $('#wrapper, #doom, #deem').filter(':visible').length === 0 ) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Hi, @adeneo your code is worked, however how can i add a <p> tag there if my html structure look like that: <div id='wrapper'>
  <div id='doom'>
    <p>
    </p>     
    </div>
  </div> I added the #wrapper and #doom but how to add the "p" ? because if i put p directly in that script that it will check all p tag in my template, but i want that it should only look for <p> tag inside that structure...it might be like this:  #wrapper p   so is there any way to add that p in that script ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is using multiple selectors by modifying your if-condition to use commas and using the is-method :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    //<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            if (!$('#wrapper, #doom, #deem').is(':visible')) window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com/'

        }, 1000)
    })
  //]]>
</script>
```

Read more on **multiple selectors** by [clicking here](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

> Description: Selects the combined results of all the specified selectors.

Read more on the **is** method by [clicking here](http://api.jquery.com/is/):

> Description: Check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element, or jQuery object and return true if at least one of these elements matches the given arguments.

Comment: check your syntax ...missing a few things

Comment: Hi, @Clayton you edit the code by removing filter and add is and believe me the code is not working if i add "is" instead of "filter" with filter its worked.

Comment: @Clayton sorry it worked i just update only the is instead of filter, but there is also some other changes made too. thanks.

Comment: what do you mean other changes?... do not understand.. anyway, I have a meeting, feel free to accept my answer if it solves your original question, thank you.

Comment: @charlietfl the code is worked, however how can i add a <p> tag there if my html structure look like that: <div id='wrapper'> <div id='doom'> <p> </p> </div> </div> I added the #wrapper and #doom but how to add the "p" ? because if i put p directly in that script that it will check all p tag in my template, but i want that it should only look for <p> tag inside that structure...it might be like this: #wrapper p so is there any way to add that p in that script ?

Comment: @Clayton your code is worked, however how can i add a <p> tag there if my html structure look like that: <div id='wrapper'> <div id='doom'> <p> </p> </div> </div> I added the #wrapper and #doom but how to add the "p" ? because if i put p directly in that script that it will check all p tag in my template, but i want that it should only look for <p> tag inside that structure...it might be like this: #wrapper p so is there any way to add that p in that script ?

Comment: Try $('#wrapper p, #doom, #deem')

Comment: @Clayton its not working i add #wrapper p but not worked,

Comment: so if you have `<div id='wrapper'> <div id='doom'> <p> </p> </div> </div>` you want to determine when that condition is `true`? `$('#wrapper p,#doom,#deem').is(':visible')` will return `true` for that condition so maybe there is something I do not understand in your question.

Comment: @Clayton exactly, yes, i want to add the <p> tag in that script that belong to <div id='wrapper'> <div id='doom'> <p> </p> </div> </div>. as there are many p <tag> exist in my template, but i only want to add the #wrapper p tag, which is inside the html structure or you can say that, the <p> tag child in <div id='wrapper'> so do it what you told me..thanks

Comment: Try $('#deem, #doom').append('<p>')